# chrome extension API refresh page in original windows

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm opening a Chrome extension as a popup window using the following code on the background.ts:

```
chrome.windows.create({
    url: chrome.runtime.getURL("index.html"),
    type: "popup",
    width: w,
    height: h,
    top: top,
    left: left,
  });
```

Something similar happens when you are in opensea.io page and you try to connect your Coinbase wallet given you have the Coinbase extension installed

[image]

After the user perform some actions on the popup (Chrome extension itself) I need to refresh the original tab. I have tried `chrome.tabs.reload(arrayOfTabs[0].id);` but the problem is the popup is treated as a different window and I can not access the original windows tab.

Any suggestions would be welcome. Thanks

Comment: You can pass the original tabId as a parameter: `url: 'index.html?' + originalTabId` then use it inside the popup as `location.search`

Comment: @wOxxOm I have the `originalTabId` in the new window, unfortunately If I try to refresh or do any other action it doesn't work because is in a separate window.

Comment: The tabs are identified by id regardless of window so there's something wrong in your code.

Comment: @wOxxOm On my Chrome extension I'm doing this


 `if (message.hasOwnProperty("action") && message.action === "refreshTab") {
    chrome.tabs.query(
      { active: true, currentWindow: true },
      function (arrayOfTabs) {
        if (arrayOfTabs.length > 0 && arrayOfTabs[0].id) {
          console.log(arrayOfTabs[0].id);
          chrome.tabs?.reload(arrayOfTabs[0].id, {});
        }
      }
    );
    return;
  }`

What could be wrong?

Comment: There's no need for chrome.tabs.query in the new window. You should save tab id in the original code, then pass it to the new window, then use this value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to to get the active and focused window assuming that was the opener tab but I has wrong.

Before

```
chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true }, (arrayOfTabs) => {
      if (arrayOfTabs.length > 0 && arrayOfTabs[0].id) {
        chrome.tabs?.reload(arrayOfTabs[0].id, {});
      }
});
```

After

```
chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, windowType: "normal" }, (arrayOfTabs) => {
      if (arrayOfTabs.length > 0 && arrayOfTabs[0].id) {
        chrome.tabs?.reload(arrayOfTabs[0].id, {});
      }
});
```

In this way I can get the opener tab. As @wOxxOm mentioned in a comment, tabs are identified regardless the window, it was all about the query I was using.